# Xcodebuild's .app crashes immediately? But Xcode's .app runs successfully

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcodebuild, .app

I'm using xcodebuild to build and install my app on the simulator (by copying the `.app` to `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/UUID/`) from the command line. I use:

```
xcodebuild -target MyApp 
           -configuration Debug
           CPU_ARCHITECTURE=iphonesimulator6.1
           install DSTROOT=Products
```

The .app is produced in `/project_root/Products/Applications/MyApp.app` However, every time I run the `.app` on my simulator, **it crashes immediately**.

I compared the `.app` that is created from Xcode's `Run` to xcodebuild's output from above. The two `MyApp.app`s are pretty much identical, but the `MyApp` binary inside of `MyApp.app` differ (the Xcode one is almost twice the memory footprint). I even tried copying the binary from Xcode's `MyApp.app` to `xcodebuild`'s, and that worked too.

Any ideas why `xcodebuild`'s .app is crashing?

Comment: Probably you haven't set the right VALID_ARCHS...

Comment: Hmm thanks for the tip, can you elaborate on that? I tried adding VALID_ARCHS="armv7 armv7s i386" and variants of those, but the `.app` is still crashing on startup. I also tried following some suggestions to set the `ARCHS` and `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` flags too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889065/no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x86-64-valid

Comment: look at all the xcodebuild options - you can set the target, the build configuration, etc - probably one of these is not being specified.

Comment: Thanks, got it working now. I also had to change `CPU_ARCHITECTURE=` to the `-sdk` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there was no explicit "answer" to my question that I can mark as correct, here's my solution just in case anybody else has the same problem. Props to Richard for pointing me in the right direction. I played around with different settings for `VALID_ARCHS` and set it to `"i386"` (the simulator's architecture). Additionally, the syntax was wrong for `CPU_ARCHITECTURE`. `xcodebuild` uses the `-sdk` option instead. The following worked for me:

```
xcodebuild -target MyApp
           -configuration Debug
           -sdk iphonesimulator6.1
           VALID_ARCHS="i386"
           install DSTROOT=Products
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my script that makes .app for simulator :

(Replace "MyApp" with your app name)

```
XCODE_WORKSPACE=/Users/MacBook/iOS/MyApp.xcworkspace
xcrun xcodebuild \
  -scheme MyApp \
  -workspace $XCODE_WORKSPACE \
  -configuration Debug \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=11.2' \
  -derivedDataPath \
  build
```