# No architectures to compile

Tags: ios

I am getting following issue:

No architectures to compile for `(ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386)`.

Can anyone suggest what error it is and how to resolve it?

Comment: This is answered [here][1]. Even Harsh copied directly the answer from there


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13134510/921789

Answer (score 1):

You can set the "Build Active Architecture Only" and "Archs" values from command line itself. We set ARCHS="i386" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO.

Eg

/usr/bin/xcodebuild ARCHS="i386" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -workspace -scheme ......

This will free you from manually changing the values in your project settings.

You can also refer the apple discussions! :)
https://devforums.apple.com/message/376732#376732

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5.1 - No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386)
you may solve this proble in build settings 
-->
"Valid Architectures"
by  add  "arm64"