# No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 i386)

Tags: ios, iphone

I am getting this error while building my iOS app.

No architectures to compile for (`ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 i386`).

I am followings errors while I am trying to use _ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:

```
"_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
  -[ClsHomePageViewController twitterLogin:] in ClsHomePageViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ClsHomePageViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And my Architecture settings are as follows:

```
architectures: Standard Architectures (including 64-bit) (armv7,armv7s,armv64)
Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 7.0)
Build Active Architecture Only: NO
Valid Architectures: arm64 armv7s armv7
```

Comment: remove armv6 from valid architectures. clean and run

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please search for older questions describing the same problem. Your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889065/no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x86-64-valid, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423800/an-error-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x86, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074113/no-architectures-to-compile etc.

Answer (score 23):

Go to your project, open `Project` (not target) ->`Build Settings` and set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO`:

[image: Change Only Active Architecture]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Please check my question, I edited question and tried to explain my issue in detail.

Comment: Thanks you so much it's save my time

Comment: why debug no? will this affect our ability to debug ?

Answer (score 3):

1.Please check your project Architectures.
You can find about architectures follow this:
[image]

From your target - Build Settings - Architectures, see the screenshot.

2.The Build Active Architecture Only the following Debug is set to YES.

Reference:iOS currently has the following instruction set:

(1). armv6, support machines iPhone, iPhone2, iPhone3G and the corresponding iTouch

(2). armv7, support machines iPhone4, iPhone4S

(3). armv7s, support machines iPhone5, iPhone5C

(4). arm64, support machines: iPhone5S

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Please check my question, I edited question and tried to explain my issue in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `armv7` in you valid architecture list.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Please check my question, I edited question and tried to explain my issue in detail.