# Swift : library not found for -lPods , linker command failed with exit code 1 ( Xcode 7.2)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to do an app for retail store , I was using Xcode 6.3 due to library issues i tried to move to Xcode 7.2 , when i tried to upgrade and run my app , i get the following error .

The following is the error

```
Ld /Users/jg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Enrico-ecxoqwtsnrjpynfphdobukwkpjdi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Enrico.app/Enrico normal x86_64
    cd /Users/jg/Documents/Workspace/Enrico
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 7.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode\ 7.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/jg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Enrico-ecxoqwtsnrjpynfphdobukwkpjdi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/jg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Enrico-ecxoqwtsnrjpynfphdobukwkpjdi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/jg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Enrico-ecxoqwtsnrjpynfphdobukwkpjdi/Build/Intermediates/Enrico.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Enrico.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Enrico.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.3 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode\ 7.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/jg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Enrico-ecxoqwtsnrjpynfphdobukwkpjdi/Build/Intermediates/Enrico.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Enrico.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Enrico.swiftmodule -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Enrico-ecxoqwtsnrjpynfphdobukwkpjdi/Build/Intermediates/Enrico.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Enrico.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Enrico_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Enrico-ecxoqwtsnrjpynfphdobukwkpjdi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Enrico.app/Enrico

ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've checked other "library not found for -lPods" on StackOverflow but i could not find a solution.Please help me to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your pod installation is wrong please go through this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS6UwD51EGg

Comment: Clean derived data and then follow my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116636/no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-armv7-valid/24116746#24116746