# Undefined symbol "__Unwind_SjLj_Unregister" under Watch SDK

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, watchkit, linker-errors

We are experiencing [Apple WatchOS build failures](https://travis-ci.org/noloader/cryptopp/builds/362992707) on Travis for a C++ library. Other configurations, like iPhone, iPhoneSimulator and AppleTV are OK.

The library compiles OK but it fails to link. A [typical compile invocation is](https://travis-ci.org/noloader/cryptopp/builds/362992707):

```
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -pipe -Wall -arch armv7 -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot \
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS3.1.sdk \
-c cryptlib.cpp

clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -pipe -Wall -arch armv7 -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot \
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS3.1.sdk \
-c cpu.cpp

clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -pipe -Wall -arch armv7 -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot \
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS3.1.sdk \
-c integer.cpp

...
```

After compile there are lots of linker errors as shown below. We are not sure if these are false positives or if we missed a necessary option or library.

I've tried searching Apple Developer but I'm having trouble finding information specific to Watch builds. I found some similar questions like [Undefined symbol compiling boost context for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24116636/608639) but they are unanswered (and the wrong platform).

I have an older MacBook for testing, but it runs OS X 10.9 and has Xcode 6. Its too old to try and work this problem. For example, it does not have WatchOS and can't decode the missing symbol name:

```
$ echo __Unwind_SjLj_Register | c++filt
__Unwind_SjLj_Register
```

Are the linking errors expected when testing this configuration? If not, then is the architecture correct? Maybe, which option or libraries are we missing for Watch and TV?

---

I found this recently in Clang source code, [`ToolChain.cpp`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ToolChains_8cpp_source.html):

```
bool Darwin::UseSjLjExceptions(const ArgList &Args) const {
   // Darwin uses SjLj exceptions on ARM.
   if (getTriple().getArch() != llvm::Triple::arm &&
       getTriple().getArch() != llvm::Triple::thumb)
     return false;

   // Only watchOS uses the new DWARF/Compact unwinding method.
   llvm::Triple Triple(ComputeLLVMTriple(Args));
   return !Triple.isWatchABI();
 }
```

---

Here's what link looks like. We drive it through the compiler, and we use the same `CXXFLAGS`.

```
clang++ -o cryptest.exe -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -pipe -Wall -arch armv7 -isysroot \
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS3.1.sdk \
-stdlib=libc++ adhoc.o test.o bench1.o bench2.o validat0.o validat1.o validat2.o validat3.o \
 datatest.o regtest1.o regtest2.o regtest3.o fipsalgt.o dlltest.o ./libcryptopp.a 

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

  "__Unwind_SjLj_Register", referenced from:
      CryptoPP::CipherModeFinalTemplate_CipherHolder<CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)0, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc>, CryptoPP::ConcretePolicyHolder<CryptoPP::Empty, CryptoPP::AdditiveCipherTemplate<CryptoPP::AbstractPolicyHolder<CryptoPP::AdditiveCipherAbstractPolicy, CryptoPP::OFB_ModePolicy> >, CryptoPP::AdditiveCipherAbstractPolicy> >::~CipherModeFinalTemplate_CipherHolder() in test.o    
      CryptoPP::Test::scoped_main(int, char**) in test.o    
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > CryptoPP::IntToString<long>(long, unsigned int) in test.o    
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char*) in test.o    
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::ws<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test.o    
      CryptoPP::Test::GenerateRSAKey(unsigned int, char const*, char const*, char const*) in test.o    
      CryptoPP::Test::RSASignFile(char const*, char const*, char const*) in test.o    
      ...

  "__Unwind_SjLj_Resume", referenced from:
      CryptoPP::CipherModeFinalTemplate_CipherHolder<CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)0, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc>, CryptoPP::ConcretePolicyHolder<CryptoPP::Empty, CryptoPP::AdditiveCipherTemplate<CryptoPP::AbstractPolicyHolder<CryptoPP::AdditiveCipherAbstractPolicy, CryptoPP::OFB_ModePolicy> >, CryptoPP::AdditiveCipherAbstractPolicy> >::~CipherModeFinalTemplate_CipherHolder() in test.o   
      CryptoPP::Test::scoped_main(int, char**) in test.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > CryptoPP::IntToString<long>(long, unsigned int) in test.o    
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char*) in test.o    
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::ws<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test.o    
      CryptoPP::Test::GenerateRSAKey(unsigned int, char const*, char const*, char const*) in test.o    
      CryptoPP::Test::RSASignFile(char const*, char const*, char const*) in test.o    
      ...
```

Comment: You noticed that `__Unwind_SjLj_Register` is an unmangled symbol? How was the library that's supposed to contain it compiled? Is that some startup code module?

Comment: @user0042 - `__Unwind_SjLj_Register` looks mangled to me, but I could be wrong. The library being compiled is shown above. Its my [testing clone](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp) of Wei Dai's [Crypto++](https://cryptopp.com/).

Comment: @user0042 - Part of the pain is, I don't have an interactive shell to look around and test things. I have to surmise offline, and then check-in to see if it works. Its a crummy way to develop.

Comment: The symbol sounds like something from a `startup.o` module (exceptions/stack unwinding). That's usually part of the standard library. Some issue with a compiler flag regarding exception behavior of the code? Sorry, I can also just guess about that here. I feel your pain.

Answer (score -1):

I think this may have been fixed by LLVM in September 2017 at [Fix SJLJ exception handling when manually chosen on a platform where it isn't default](https://reviews.llvm.org/D38252).

I also recently came across this from a patch, which may fix the issue. [`cfe/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.rst`](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.rst):

```
.. option:: -fsjlj-exceptions

Use SjLj style exceptions
```