# working fine in device, then I run in simulator, working great.When I want to run in device again, it fails

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using xcode6. My device is iphone ios 7.1. My app worked great on device, then I tried to run in the simulator, which is also working fine. But when I tried to rerun in the device. It shows Undefined symbols for architecture arm64. I followed this link [No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889065/no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x86-64-valid).
Remove arm64 and armv6. When I rerun it, it shows 
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s armv6).
If i add arm64 and armv6, the previous error will show again.

I had this issue so many times.

Comment: are you using some third party library ?

Comment: yes I am using some third party library. I "fixed" my problem by pulling my previous version from git.